# Formatting an output from data retrieved from a CSV file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Basically I'm trying to remove the row index (2) and I think the type information (bottom line of output) from the variable 'speed'. The code
is meant to retrieve information from a csv file at a certain location, but I only want the value of that location (1.5), rather than the rest of it. I have looked around but I couldn't find anything that applies to my problem

Code:

```
def statRetriever():
    statType = int(input("Would you like the stats of a:\n\t1. Kart\n\t2. Wheel\n\t3. Glider\n\t4. Character\nEnter your number here: "))
    if statType == 1:
        openCSV = pd.read_csv("kartStats.csv")
        kartName = input("Enter the name of the kart you wants stats for: ")
        rowNum = openCSV.index[openCSV['Name'] == kartName].tolist() # this gets the index/row number of the row where the kart name is equal to the user inputed one
        speed = openCSV.iloc[rowNum,1] # iloc can take integers in lists!
        print(f"{kartName}\n--Speed: {speed}")
```

Output:

```
Mario Kart 8 Deluxe Toolkit
Which tool would you like to use?
        1. Randomiser
        2. Stat Viewer
Enter your number here: 2
Would you like the stats of a:
        1. Kart
        2. Wheel
        3. Glider
        4. Character
Enter your number here: 1
Enter the name of the kart you wants stats for: Mach 8
Mach 8
--Speed: 2   1.5
Name: Speed, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case there is no need to look for the index/row number of the row where the kart name is equal to the user inputed one and use it later. If you change

```
rowNum = openCSV.index[openCSV['Name'] == kartName].tolist() # this gets the index/row number of the row where the kart name is equal to the user inputed one
speed = openCSV.iloc[rowNum,1] # iloc can take integers in lists!
```

to

```
speed = openCSV[openCSV['Name'] == kartName].iloc[0, 1]
```

you will get the the speed without the row index and the datatype details.